# Correct ways of (easy) porting OSS to Android?

Tags: android, native

Let's say I'm willing to port an open source software (OSS) named 'foo' to native Android (using the NDK and it's standalone toolchain). Since 'foo' depends on a LOT of shared libraries, and since I don't want to struggle too much with cross-compilation, my first thought was to retrieve the dependencies from an ARM port of Ubuntu using the dependencies from the apt tools running on QEMU :

```
> apt-get build-dep foo
```

The idea behind is to compile 'foo' statically (excepted libc of course) against the dependencies from the Ubuntu ARM filesystem. Am I completely wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring possible license issues. It is better to see if you have something close to replace some of the dependencies with (to conserve limited space and memory on the device).